# Read Async Object Set Using Await

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

A global object has its key/value (`thing`) is set in an async function `setter();` using `await`. How to asynchronously read the value of `thing` in another async function `getter();`?

I'm getting undefined error because the `getter();` is running before the `await` in `setter();` completes.

```
let obj = {};

async function af() {
    return 1;
}

(async function setter () {
  obj.thing = await af();
})();

(async function getter () {
  let thing = obj.thing;
})();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should wait for setter function to finish, you're getting a race condition problem with this approach.

An example of how that would work would be:

```
var obj = {};

async function af() {
    return 1;
}

(async function() {
    await (async function setter () {
      obj.thing = await af();
    })();

    await (async function getter () {
      let thing = obj.thing;
    })();

    console.log(obj.thing);
})();
```

At the end of the function it should log 1 that is returned on af function